# I'm working on a rock paper scissors project in tkinter and i dont know why it doesnt show the winner doesnt work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was writing a rock paper scissors program with tkinter which has rock paper scissors buttons and a button for spinning and a place for showing rock, paper or scissors.
My problem starts where i fixed the errors which was for the variable "user_choice_value" which wasn't defined.Then I ran my code and happily it showed everything but the win_lose_label.pack() at the if/else statements doesnt work.
I would be happy if u help me :)
this is my code:
(btw you can download any pic u want doesnt matter)
`

```
from tkinter import * 
from random import * 

# making the window and settings of it
window = Tk()
window.title("Rock Paper Scissor game")
window.geometry("600x600")
window.config(bg="grey")

#defining the user choices etc.
def user_choice_value(args):
   if args == "Rock":
      user_choice_value = 0
   if args == "Paper":
      user_choice_value = 1
   if args == "Scissors":
      user_choice_value = 2
   return user_choice_value

#bringing the images
rock = PhotoImage(file="python/image/rock.png")
paper = PhotoImage(file="python/image/paper.png")
scissor = PhotoImage(file="python/image/scissor.png")

#throwing and image
images_list = [rock, paper, scissor]
random_number = randint(0,2)
disp_image = Label(window, image=images_list[random_number], height=250, width=250)
disp_image.pack(pady=50)

#Determining the winner.
win_lose_label = Label(window)


if user_choice_value == random_number:
   win_lose_label.config(text="Your choice is same as computer's choice... It's a Tie!")
   win_lose_label.pack()
elif user_choice_value == 0:
   if random_number == 2:
      win_lose_label.config(text="You won!!! Your choice was rock and the computer's choice was scissors.")
      win_lose_label.pack()
   else:
      win_lose_label.config(text="You lost!!! Your choice was rock and the computer's choice was paper.")
      win_lose_label.pack()
elif user_choice_value == 1:
   if random_number == 0:
      win_lose_label.config(text="You won!!! Your choice was paper and the computers choice was rock.")
      win_lose_label.pack()
   else:
      win_lose_label.config(text="You lost!!! Your choice was paper but the computers choice was scissors.")
      win_lose_label.pack()

elif user_choice_value == 2:
   if random_number == 1:
      win_lose_label.config(text="You won!!! Your choice was scissors but the computers choice was paper.")
      win_lose_label.pack()
   else:
      win_lose_label.config(text="You lost!!! Your choice was scissors but the computer's choice was rock.")
      win_lose_label.pack()

#spin button to bring a random image
def spin_button():
   random_number = randint(0,2)
   disp_image.config(image=images_list[random_number])

spin_button = Button(window, text="Spin!", command=spin_button, width=5)
spin_button.pack()

#rock, paper, scissor buttons
rock_button = Button(window, text="Rock", width=5)
rock_button.place(x = 232, y = 320)


paper_button = Button(window, text="Paper", width=5)
paper_button.place(x = 282, y = 320)


scissor_button = Button(window, text="Scissor", width=5)
scissor_button.place(x = 332, y = 320)

window.mainloop()
```

`

I tried manipulate some things like parantheses or change the position some of the labels and these stuff but it didn't work.
Also this is the video that I've been watching it for making a rock paper scissors game in python w/ tkinter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDiPqfFF7pw&ab_channel=Codemy.com

Comment: You are performing your win/tie/lose comparisons *once*, as your program is starting up - long before the player can possibly have made their choice.  Even if you moved that code to a function, you can't tell what the player's choice was - your three Buttons do nothing.  You need to entirely rethink the structure of your program.

Comment: so my guess is that i have to make a while loop and ask each time the the player if he wants to play or not. am I right?

Comment: No, don't put a `while` loop into `tkinter` code; that'll just cause more problems. I suggest you put the win/tie/lose comparisons in a function that's called when the user selects one of the rock/paper/scissors buttons.